# Example where second derivative zero but neither extreme nor inflection point

Tags: calculus

I'm looking for an example where a differential (any number of times) function  has a zero value at a point for the second derivative but the point is neither an extremum point , neither an inflection point.
I know this implies that the first derivative is non zero at the point and the first non zero derivative at the point must be an even numbered derivative but I know of no actual example of this phenomenon.

After posting this question, I thought of the example y=mx+n, but this is of little interest since it has no curvature at any point (and fulfills the condition at every point).
It would be strange if this was the only example..

Comment: Perhaps, play around with  $x^5\sin(1/x)$.

Comment: Nice idea. We could define a function like this with a value 0 for x=0. Unfortunately, the first derivative of this function is not continuous so we can't say that this function fulfills the condition..

Comment: With $f$ as you descibe, the first derivative is $f'(x)=5x^4 \sin(1/x)-x^3\cos(1/x)$ for non-zero $x$, and $0$ for $x=0$. This is differentiable (everywhere), with $f''(0)=0$.

Comment: Youre right. My mistake. Thanks for the example. Would you agree that the only examples of this situation are similar to this one i.e. functions (and their 1st and 2nd derivatives)  that oscillate infinitely  at the problematic point thus being neither an inflection point nor an extremum point?